# Align TextView with Radio Button label

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

The goal is to align some element (`TextInputView` for example) that is under `RadioButton` with the `Radio Buttons` label. Example:
[image]
As  you can see, the label right to `Radio Buttons` should be aligned with the element underneath. I doubt setting simple static margin will help.

Example code, where I used left margin:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/exactPriceRadio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set hourly rate"
            app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.bitreg.bitregmobile.widgets.PriceEditText
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:hint="Enter exact price"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But left margin solution is insufficient because it's a hardcoded value, not dynamically aligned.

Comment: did you try margin?

Comment: Yes, for now I use hand picked margin but it will need to be different for each device. I don't think that's a great solution unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: for each device you need to create xml as per size

Comment: @Necroqubus post your xml code here.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti Added example code

Comment: @KurtAcosta Added example code

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan that will work, but I think it's a bad solution. I need to know how big are the paddings and margins around radio button icon and add radio button size to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RadioButton` with empty label + `TextView` to display the label. This way you need to align you `EditText` with that `TextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mvl.dagger2testapp.MainActivity">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Label For RadioBUtton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you